# Get information about the route executed in Fat Free v3

Tags: routes, fat-free-framework

I'd like to know which route is executed according to current URL in the `beforeRoute` method in the Fat Free Framework.

In other words, can I get which class and which method will be executed? I had info about about the pattern (URL) in PATTERN variable but I don't know which class and method is going to be executed for this PATTERN as mapped in routes.ini.

Example of my routes.ini:

```
GET /admin=Controllers\Admin\Admin->index
```

In this case I'd like to find that the class is `Controllers\Admin\Admin` and the method is index.

I've found how to get the class:

```
get_class($this)
```

But I haven't found how to get the method name. Please remember that I have to get the method name from the `beforeRoute` method.

Answer (score 5):

i've foud it here is the solution, it may help some one.

To get the method name that will be executed in the route :

```
$hive = $f3->hive();
$tmp = explode('->',$hive['ROUTES'][$f3->get('PATTERN')][3][$hive['VERB']][0]);
```

So $tmp[0] will contain the class name and
$tmp[1] will containt de method name.

Answer (score 3):

short and sweet version

```
$request = $this->f3->get('PARAMS.0');
```

then you can check if the $request has what you are looking for

**Example**

```
if(!$this->f3->exists('SESSION.userId')){
    if (!$this->strpos($request,'login')) {
        $this->f3->reroute('/login');
        exit;
    }
}
```

**More details on PARAM**

The first array index of PARAM contains the URI, from there PARAM will contain any route query variables.

Sample URL: http://localhost/user/edit/@id/@whatever

```
PARAMS[0]=/user/edit/foo/bar
PARAMS[id]=foo
PARAMS[whatever]=bar
```