# Get information about matched route in Fat Free version 2.0.x

Tags: php, routes, fat-free-framework

I'm using the legacy version 2.0 of Fat Free Framework. I'm bolting on some code that needs to be called for every request.

I want to examine the route matched, which I find I can do in the `beforeRoute` method using this:

```
$routeData = F3::get('PARAMS');
```

If the route is defined thus:

```
F3::route('GET /@customer/dictionary/@key', 'controllers\dictionaries->viewKey');
```

Then examining `$routeData` gives:

```
array(
    [0] => /custname/dictionary/mykey
    [customer] => custname
    [key] => mykey
)
```

That's a good start, but I'd like to obtain `GET /@customer/dictionary/@key` or just `/@customer/dictionary/@key`. I suppose I could swap out the key values with regexs and do a match this way, but it'd be nice to have a cleaner way to do it!

Note this question [has already been asked for version 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16575687/get-information-about-the-route-executed-in-fat-free-v3), which is no good for me at present. We'd like to upgrade, but that's not possible at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of release 2.1.0, you can get:

- the request method with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` (no dedicated F3 variable in version 2)
- the matched route pattern with `F3::get('PATTERN')`
- the matched route parameters with `F3::get('PARAMS')`

So in your case:

```
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];// GET
echo F3::get('PATTERN');// /@customer/dictionary/@key
echo F3::get('PARAMS.customer');// custname
echo F3::get('PARAMS.key');// mykey
```

Comment: Thanks. However - sorry! - I should have been more specific on the version number. It's 2.0.12 in our case. I guess that's very old `:)`.

Comment: The `PATTERN` variable was introduced later I fear. If you don't want to risk an upgrade to [2.1.0](https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree/blob/archive/f3-2.1.0.release.zip), you can patch your base.php by adding the following line `self::$vars['PATTERN']=$uri;` in function `run()` right after `$found=TRUE`. It should be located around line 1296.

Comment: That would be a possibility - yeah, it didn't look like the `run` function method captured which route it matched. Alright, thanks for the help!